# Hello, I want to add a 100 amp panel for multiple RV services

Tags: service

I want to add a panel for 2 RV plugs at 50 amps each and have 4 110volt plugs. I like doing things myself so I know what is going on, on my own property. I know I'll have to have it inspected by an electrician to be approved but to save cost of hours I'll do all the work myself and have it inspected along the way. So I have a 200 amp service that I will be connecting to, the run will be approximately 300 ft, I already own 4/0 aluminum cable 600ft long and the 100amp service panel that I want to go to. It will all be buried in conduit from main panel to sub panel. I'm just wondering if the 4/0 will be sufficient to carry that load with no issues?  I don't want to drop another $4000.00 on cable if I can avoid it. I want the 110 services to be 30 amps per 2. So is this possible or should I consider something else?

Comment: Don't buy another solitary thing, not even a knockout cover, until you've drawn up a detailed plan and people here and on forums have stopped advising changes. You could have wasted $4000 ( I think you didn't, but making the most out of thin wire is my hat.)  Preferring DIY is awesome. But it puts all the onus on you to have your knowledge/plan tip top.  [Shoddy DIY work](https://www.cnn.com/2016/08/11/us/california-valley-fire-faulty-hot-tub/index.html) is so universal that it's practically Pavlovian for inspectors to reject it.

Comment: Now, do you need to power two RVs at the same time? Or do you simply want to provide 20/30/30/50 to support a variety of RVs in one spot?

Comment: How many wires are in that 4/0 cable of yours, and is it a sheathed/jacketed cable, or a direct bury multiplex?

Comment: Also, prepare to upsize the panel because 4/0 wire will not fit on a 100A breaker, and the cheapest way to resolve that is to upsize the panel. Upsizing the subpanel is no problem, in fact it's a good idea.  If your hope was to have the remote breaker trip first, lol doesn't work, but there are other things we can do to help.

Comment: The op could pigtail at the panel to a smaller size. Since the size is just for voltage drop.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. We'll need more info before we can help you. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.